# Making buttonCheckAnswer visible after checking first radioButton

Tags: java, android

In this method the `buttonCheckAnswer` is shown after **all** `rbs` are checked.

```
public static void checkSelected() {

    boolean check = true;
    for (boolean radioChecked : checked) {
        if(Boolean.TRUE != radioChecked){
            check = false;

        }
    }
    if (check)
        buttonCheckAnswer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

What is the `else statement` for this method to get the `buttonCheckAnswer` to be shown right after **the first** `rb` is checked?

**POST UPDATE**

Since now the `buttonCheckAnswer` is displayed right after the first `rb` is checked, I would like to add one more `Key answer` `"You haven't checked all answers"`

Now so far I have two options in MainActivity

```
buttonCheckAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(checkAnswers())
                intent.putExtra("KEY_ANSWER", true);
            else
                intent.putExtra("KEY_ANSWER", false);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

And I've already added to `MainActivity` this method for this "You haven't checked all answers"

```
private boolean allAnswersChecked() {
    boolean answered = true;
    for (boolean radioAnswer : isAnswered)
        answered = answered && radioAnswer;
    return answered;
}
```

and also two options in `AnswerActivity`

```
TextView textViewDisplayResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_display_result);

    textViewDisplayResult.setText(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("KEY_ANSWER", false)?R.string.Good_answer:R.string.Wrong_answer);
```

Comment: You can use a counter, I guess

Comment: can you explain details, how many radio button there and when checkSelected method will call and what you what to do in else part?

Comment: Thanks for advice, Jose.

Comment: @Lingeshwaran ,Hirsto gave the perfect solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep it simple:

```
public static void checkSelected() {
    for (boolean radioChecked : checked) {
        if(true == radioChecked){
            buttonCheckAnswer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution! :) Many thanks Hristo :) Can you help me with one more thing? I'll update my post in a sec..

Comment: What seems to be the problem? Ping me on chat it would be easier

Comment: I have to have 20 reputation to talk on chat :( so maybe I can explain more to you here. Now I have two "Key answers"  - "Good answers" and "Wrong answers" for which I have set method `buttonCheckAnswer`. Now I'd like  to add to this method one more "Key answer" which is "You haven't checked all answers" and pass it to `AnswerActivity`. Both `MainActivity` and `AnswerActivity` are shown above in my code.

Comment: Hi again, the easiest way would be to add a new extra like this :             intent.putExtra("KEY_ALL_CHECKED", allAnswersChecked()); You can ping me on skype/mail hristo.j.s@gmail.com if you need more help. Cheers

Comment: Fantastic Hristo. I'll try to work it out and will mail you for more help if needed. Many thanks!

Comment: ..and Hristo, how to add your solution to this line `textViewDisplayResult.setText(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("KEY_ANSWER", false)?R.string.Good_answer:R.string.Wrong_answer);` in this  `ActivityAnswer`?

Answer (score 0):

try this: Use `break` in for loop

```
public static void checkSelected() {

    boolean check = true;
    for (boolean radioChecked : checked) {
        if(Boolean.TRUE != radioChecked){
            check = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (check)
        buttonCheckAnswer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Glad it worked.Please accept my answer.You can also visit : https://stackoverflow.com/tour to get more information about SO and support me as much as you can.

Comment: It didn't work Bhupat. Hristo just below gave the best solution. I've updated my post so if you wanna try to help so more I will appreciate it.